# Recommendations on implementing a static many-to-one lookup in my Android app

Tags: android, lookup, many-to-one

I need to perform a many-to-one lookup in my Android app. I store a number of phone area codes, and the states they map to. For example, 516, 518, 914 all map to New York, 213, 408, 949 are all CA etc.

My app needs to lookup this information only rarely - a few times in its lifetime.

What is the best way to store it? I could store it in an XML resource file as an Array, or in prefs.xml. I could also incorporate it as a static array (or Set) in the application. Finally I could use a DB.

My goal is to reduce the bloat on the APK size, since this data is so infrequently used. Secondary goal is to keep this manageable, and avoid touching code when data changes.

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is relative.  I'd suggest keeping the mapping in xml string array resources (is there a 'map' resource?) because it will be easier to update.  I don't think the size will be that big of a deal (don't quote me on that, though).  If size was critical, I'd either create a Sqlite DB outside of the app, and put it in the assets folder, possibly gzipped.  You could also define your own text file format and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The size of this mapping should not be a big problem in terms of increasing the APK size. `XML` resource seems to me the best way to go about doing this. In my opinion, that is the simplest and native way(should always be preffered) of solving these kind of problems.

Comment: Pramod, Kevin: Yes, I tend to agree that the XML resources are best place for such static data. However, List/Map/Set etc do not seem to be available as resource types (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html). For my application, I need a .contains(), so I decided to create a separate abstract class, and threw the data in there as follows: static HashSet<Integer> NY_US = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(516,518 ... )). My app seems to have survived :-)